# How to conduct a MANCOVA

Tags: r, manova

I am trying to perform a mancova in R. However,  I have tried the [jmv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jmv/jmv.pdf) package:

```
x<-cbind('total.c','total.p') #dependent
y<-cbind('Treatment','Sex', 'Species', 'Location') #independent
mancova(intake, deps=x,factors=y, covs=c("Ghopper.Start..g."))
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Error: Table$setRow(): value 'stat[pillai]' is not atomic
```

When I remove one of the independent variables, the function works with no problems. So I am suspecting its a memory limitation,, but what actually is going wrong here?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Only works for 3 factors